# How to pass scope data to directive without attribute

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with isolate scope. I can pass a parent attribute to it ('ts' below). But is there a way to pass parent scope data to the isolate scope WITHOUT using an attribute?

In other words, I want to have my directive definition access a parent scope's value (ts) without sending that in an attribute written in the html. (I read that using $parent is frowned upon.)

Reason: Using an attribute works, but it looks like a kludge. I'm trying to write a component and the user shouldn't have to add attributes (in this case, "ts='ts'") for me to make my component work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rrosen326/WWYuD/

```
<div  ng-app="testapp">
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
         <h1>Test of Directive</h1>

        <button ng-click="setData_ts()">Get Data</button>
        <chart-dir num='1' ts='ts'></chart-dir>
        <chart-dir num='2' ts='ts'></chart-dir>
    </div>
</div>

var app = angular.module('testapp', [])
    .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.ts = -1; // timestamp 

    $scope.setData_ts = function () {
        $scope.ts = new Date().getTime();
    };

}

app.directive('chartDir', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            ts: '=',
            num: '@'
        },
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><h3>Chart {{num}}</h3><p>Time Stamp: {{ts}}</p></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            scope.$watch('ts', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                // Data received - update charts
                console.log("DATA RECEIVED", newValue);
            });


        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Me too. I want to work without attributes to pass scope data to directive. For example in **knockout ko**: `<div data-bind="MyWidget: MyWidgetSettings">`. **MyWidgetSettings** is a complex object with multiples variables.

Answer (score 3):

> Using an attribute works, but it looks like a kludge. I'm trying to write a component and the user shouldn't have to add attributes (in this case, "ts='ts'") for me to make my component work.

It is not a kludge.  Attributes make your directive reusable with different controllers that may chose to use different $scope property names:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
   <chart-dir num='1' ts='ts1'></chart-dir>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
   <chart-dir num='2' ts='ts2'></chart-dir>
</div>
```

Stated another way, a directive should normally not hard-code/assume $scope property names.

Users of your directive should have to add attributes to specify which data the directive will need to do its job.

Comment: Ah - ok, that makes sense. Never thought of it that way.

Answer (score 2):

have you considered using $broadcast event to communicate between your controllers (the controller in each directive is a children of your main Ctrl() controller)

I forked your fiddle in order to show you how I would have done it : http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/YQ2Tq/1/

On the HTML side I modified a bit your code, I deleted the 'ts' attributes and modified the called function in the ng-click :

```
<button ng-click="broadcast_ts()">Get Data</button>
    <chart-dir num='1'></chart-dir>
    <chart-dir num='2'></chart-dir>
```

on the JS side, I defined the broadcast_ts function, which broadcast an event (I called it "hello", but you can define any name) and send data (I didn't send any useful data, but you could for example send your new 'ts' value in it):

```
$scope.broadcast_ts=function()
   {
       $scope.$broadcast('hello',{"values":'I was broadcasted'})   
   }
```

Then, in the directive, I defined a $on method, to catch the broadcasted event :

```
scope.$on('hello', function(event, args){
                scope.ts=new Date().getTime();
                console.log("DATA RECEIVED", args.values);
            })
```

This method recalculates the new ts (you can see in the fiddle that there is a tiny difference in the timestamps) but you could totally use another value, or any object passed in the arguments of broadcast

Comment: Hey - that's a great idea.  I'll still keep it open to see if there is a direct way of just passing the scope value down, but perhaps this is the preferred method anyway. Thanks.

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that it now couples the controller and the directive -- i.e., the event name can't change without updating code in both.  Attributes don't have this problem.